# How to select and filter a formula in one calculation

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Is there some way to have a formula that is in both the select and where condition only be calculated once?

I assume mysql must do the calculation twice for each row it the following example.

```
SELECT z1.id sid1,z2.id sid2,SQRT(POW(ABS(z1.col-z2.col),2) + POW(ABS(z1.row-z2.row),2)) r
    FROM stars z1,stars z2
    WHERE z1.id!=z2.id
    AND SQRT(POW(ABS(z1.col-z2.col),2) + POW(ABS(z1.row-z2.row),2)) <=32
    ORDER BY z1.id,z2.id
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the performance of math operations.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but as you create an alias `r` for `SQRT(POW(ABS(z1.col-z2.col),2) + POW(ABS(z1.row-z2.row),2))`, can't you just do something like `AND r <= 32`?

Comment: @Kohányi been trying that, but can't get it to work

Comment: @Mahks Ah, yeah, I knew there was some trickery with queries like this. Jan Dvorak got it right, I totally forgot about the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to aliases defined in a `SELECT` clause in a `WHERE` clause, but you can use them in a `HAVING` clause. This is because `WHERE` is evaluated before `SELECT` as `SELECT` may contain aggregate functions.

```
SELECT z1.id sid1,z2.id sid2,SQRT(POW(ABS(z1.col-z2.col),2) + POW(ABS(z1.row-z2.row),2)) r
 FROM stars z1,stars z2
 WHERE z1.id != z2.id
 HAVING r <= 32
 ORDER BY z1.id,z2.id
```

Beware, though, that the `HAVING` clause will most likely not be used in indexes. You could provide an approximate term to the `WHERE` clause for indexing purposes:

```
SELECT z1.id sid1,z2.id sid2,SQRT(POW(ABS(z1.col-z2.col),2) + POW(ABS(z1.row-z2.row),2)) r
 FROM stars z1,stars z2
 WHERE z1.id != z2.id
 AND (z2.col BETWEEN z1.col-32 AND z1.col+32)
 AND (z2.row BETWEEN z1.row-32 AND z1.row+32)
 HAVING r <= 32
 ORDER BY z1.id,z2.id
```

Note that the bottleneck is disk access, not arithmetic calculation, so if you are optimising for speed, you may want to stay with WHERE and only optimise the WHERE clause:

note that

- x^2 is the same as abs(x)^2.
- x*x is likely faster than pow(x,2)
- instead of computing the sqrt, you can square the other side.

Try:

```
SELECT z1.id sid1,z2.id sid2,
  SQRT((z1.col-z2.col)*(z1.col-z2.col) + (z1.row-z2.row)*(z1.row-z2.row)) r
 FROM stars z1,stars z2
 WHERE z1.id != z2.id
 AND (z1.col-z2.col)*(z1.col-z2.col) + (z1.row-z2.row)*(z1.row-z2.row) <= 1024
 ORDER BY z1.id,z2.id
```

Comment: @Mahks Try running your queries (with and without `HAVING`) through [MySQL's `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to find out why one is slower than the other.

Comment: I get the same report with either method, but don't really understand what I am seeing

Comment: appreciate the help, I think some braces are missing... returned too many rows ... but fast

Comment: Managed to cut the time by half by using a sub-query. Your idea for using the BETWEEN statement, did the job, thanks.

Comment: @Mahks What about the last option?

Comment: removal of the POW helped a bit, but the BETWEEN idea was the major help, thanks again

Comment: @Mahks As I said, `pow` is just math. Math won't kill you. The lack of indexes will.

Answer (score 0):

Please, note, what you don't really need to calculate this expression

```
SQRT(POW(ABS(z1.col-z2.col),2) + POW(ABS(z1.row-z2.row),2)) <=32
```

First, you may avoid calculating SQRT, which is, generally, slow and not absolutely accurate, by raising both parts of the expression to power 2. After this it turns to equal, but more accurate and fast

```
POW(ABS(z1.col-z2.col),2) + POW(ABS(z1.row-z2.row),2) <= 1024
```

Second, you're raising ABS(z1.col-z2.col) to power 2, but you don't need ABS here, because it don't really affect the result of POW.

```
z1.col = 4, z2.col = 2   => pow(4-2, 2) = pow(2,2) = 2*2 = 4
z1.col = 2, z2.col = 4   => pow(2-4, 2) = pow(-2,2) = -2*-2 = 4
```

So,

```
POW(z1.col-z2.col,2) + POW(z1.row-z2.row,2) <= 1024
```

will made query much faster.

Comment: only marginal increase in speed.

Comment: Depends on table size. You may not fill it on 10,000's. Regardless, real MySQL bottleneck is reading files from disk, as Jan Dvorak mentioned